# How to go back to original clean installation of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 (with the additional ppa backports to get LTS) in three desktop PCs and one laptop.

But, one of the desktop PCs was sequentially upgraded from old versions up the today last version. In other words, in this PC there was not a "full clean" installation.

As the three desktop are exactly the same machines, I suspect that a lot of audio problems I only have in that specific PC are related with the fact it was not a "full clean" installation.

Can I automatically reset and back the system to the original "full clean" installation, without to have to use the Live DVD way?

How?

I'm talking about some automatic way to full erase all the apps and libraries from the old versions whith some compatibility problems with the last version.

Comment: The problem could be your user setup, as the long-updated machine may have older config files.  The only way I can think of is a re-install (using something-else without format) which notes your additional software, wipes system directories clean, installs, then add backs your additional packages without touching user directories. If however the problem with your sound setup is a user configuration file change made years ago in your $HOME directory; the problem may still remain as user files (thus configs) are not changed (if issue is a user configuration).

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: If you read the description of the backports PPA, it says you should use ppa-purge to remove it prior to upgrade. This is also noted in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, though you should use each with caution as ny automated solution could accidentally remove something vital:

[Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter)

Here's a description from [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/reset-ubuntu-desktop-default-settings):

> A new Linux app currently in beta claims to let you do exactly that:
>   reset Ubuntu, clear out all the non-default apps, remove old kernels,
>   and even purge surplus user accounts.

If support for your distribution isn't there it can be added following instructions [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0wsPzO355o).

[Reset dconf](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop-to-default)

OMG Ubuntu has detailed a way to reset your desktop to its default configuration simply by running:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

> Running this command will reset, among other things: the apps pinned
>   to the Unity launcher or Ubuntu Dock ; panel applets and/or
>   indicators; monitor resolution and interface scaling; keyboard
>   shortcuts; fonts, GTK and icon theme; window button placement,
>   launcher behaviour; and so on.
>
> This command will also reset any application that uses dconf to store its settings. >This includes core desktop apps like Rhythmbox, Evince, Shotwell and Nautilus.

Comment: This doesn't work as Ubuntu Studio uses Xfce by default.